# Is there a way to know the production and consumption rates of houses and factories?

Tags: anno-2070

Farms produce stuff (tea, vegetables, rice) at certain rates while houses consume them at certain rates (to fulfull needs). Factories also take such commodities and make something else at certain rates (such as rice and vegetables which are turned into... sushi or something).

Is there any way to see what those rates are? Knowing how many houses or citizens a single tea plantation or fishery could satisfy would be great.

Comment: I don't think it's based on house consumption rates; as you upgrade the housing, it opens up space for more people, and thus you get more people.  It's probably more based on population.  What I usually do, though, is check to see how my existing stocks are faring, or click on a specific house.  If the stocks are rising, and the needs stay full, then I have enough.  If not, I put down more industry to generate that resource.  Sadly, that's too imprecise to really answer your question, though.

Comment: @Frank Honestly, three fisheries have always been enough to feed a metropolis so right now I'm curious whether the population size actually has any impact. Also, not related to the question but do you know if there's any way to ajust cargo size in trade routes besides the slider? Ajusting a single unit is a pita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several calculators available that you can plug the production values in an get the amount of people a number of factories can supply [here](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Calculators).

However the key is generally making sure your production chains are the most efficient they can be and when it one chain becomes insufficient, build another entire chain (or part of). [This](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Production_Chains?file=Production-Chains-ANNO2070-2.jpg) image gives all that information, I have it open whenever I play Anno 2070.

Finally, in response to your question in your comment to your question: Yes you can change the cargo size in trade routes, warehouse, ships etc. All you have to do is click on the number itself, maybe double click, I can't remember! Anyway when you do it becomes editable like a normal text box.

Hope that helps.